# Scrapy: ItemLoader, can someone explain to me this error?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a question, I've started using Scrapy over the BeautifulSoup  and I new to Scrapy so this error threw me away, I've tried to fix it bit with no success.

I wanted to use Item Loader to yield scraped items, but I get error, I do not understand what is the problem.

Can someone explain to me what am I doing wrong.

This is my spider code, quotes.py :

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from quotes_spider.items import QuotesSpiderItem

class QuotesSpider(Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    allowed_domains = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ["http://quotes.toscrape.com"]


    def parse(self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item=QuotesSpiderItem(), response=response)
        quotes = response.xpath('//*[@class="quote"]')
        for quote in quotes:
            text = quote.xpath('.//*[@class="text"]/text()').extract_first()
            author = quote.xpath('.//*[@itemprop="author"]/text()').extract_first()
            tags = quote.xpath('.//*[@class="tag"]/text()').extract_first ()

            l.add_value('Text', text)
            l.add_value('Author', author)
            l.add_value('Tags', tags)

            return l.load_item()
```

This is my items.py file:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpiderItem(scrapy.Item):
    text = scrapy.Field()
    author = scrapy.Field()
    tags = scrapy.Field()
```

This the error that I get when I try to run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/djurovic/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/djurovic/Desktop/quotes_spider/quotes_spider/spiders/quotes.py", line 20, in parse
    l.add_value('Text', text)
  File "/home/djurovic/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/loader/__init__.py", line 77, in add_value
    self._add_value(field_name, value)
  File "/home/djurovic/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/loader/__init__.py", line 91, in _add_value
    processed_value = self._process_input_value(field_name, value)
  File "/home/djurovic/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/loader/__init__.py", line 148, in _process_input_value
    proc = self.get_input_processor(field_name)
  File "/home/djurovic/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/loader/__init__.py", line 137, in get_input_processor
    self.default_input_processor)
  File "/home/djurovic/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/loader/__init__.py", line 154, in _get_item_field_attr
    value = self.item.fields[field_name].get(key, default)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no fields `Text`, `Author` and `Tags` in `QuotesSpiderItem`, their names are `text`, `author` and `tags`. Letter case matters.

Comment: Thank a lot, did not expect that, it would affect it.

Comment: I more question I noticed that it only appends the first one. and doesn't go to the next quote , do you know the reason?

Comment: Yeah, you are doing `return` at the end of the cycle, so your function terminates.

Comment: I fixed it just moved the return statement outside the for loop